# JavaScript not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my code there are 4 select boxes. All of their default value is '--'. The 1st one is enabled by default and all other is disabled and empty. If I select 1st one then next one gets enabled and fetch its value from a php script. The problem is, if I select '--' in the 2nd list then the remaining do not get empty and disabled but they should. For example If I select a value from 2nd one then third one fetches its value but if I select '--' then the third one holds an php warning that is generated from the external script. The warning is as follows:

```
  ( ! ) Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 4, column 18: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_COST_CENTERS' ORA-06550: line 4, column 9: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in D:\wamp\www\Cost_Center\ajax - Copy.php on line 18 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0002247680{main}(  )..\ajax - Copy.php:0 20.0397249536oci_execute (  )..\ajax - Copy.php:18  

  ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\Cost_Center\ajax - Copy.php on line 23 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0002247680{main}(  )..\ajax - Copy.php:0
```

These errors should not generate because in my JavaScript script I have checked that if any select box holds '--' then it will never call the ajax function, but instead it does I don't know why. What is the problem? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <select id="region_type">
        <option>--</option>
    <?php 
        //fetching the options of #region_type       
    ?>     
    </select>
    <select id="main_region" disabled='true'>
    </select>
    <select id="sub_main_region" disabled='true'>
    </select>
    <select id="specific_location" disabled='true'>
    </select>
    <script>
    $("body").on('change', '#region_type', function( e ) {
        if($('#region_type').val()=='--'){
            document.getElementById("main_region").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("main_region").disabled='true';

            document.getElementById("sub_main_region").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("sub_main_region").disabled='true';

            document.getElementById("specific_location").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("specific_location").disabled='true';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("main_region").removeAttribute('disabled');
            get_main_region(e);
        }

    });
    $("body").on('change', '#main_region', function( e ) {
        if($('#main_region').val()=='--'){
            document.getElementById("sub_main_region").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("sub_main_region").disabled='true';

            document.getElementById("specific_location").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("specific_location").disabled='true';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("sub_main_region").removeAttribute('disabled');
            get_sub_main_region(e);
        }
    });

    $("body").on('change', '#sub_main_region', function( e ) {
        if($('#sub_main_region').val()=='--'){
            document.getElementById("specific_location").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("specific_location").disabled='true';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("specific_location").removeAttribute('disabled');
            get_specific_location(e);
        }
    });



    function get_main_region(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax - Copy.php',
            type:'POST',
            async:true,
            data:{
                var1: $('#region_type').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                document.getElementById("main_region").innerHTML=response.toString();
            }
        });
    }
    function get_sub_main_region(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax - Copy.php',
            type:'POST',
            async:true,
            data:{
                var1: $('#main_region').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                document.getElementById("sub_main_region").innerHTML=response;
            }
        });
    }
    function get_specific_location(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax - Copy.php',
            type:'POST',
            async:true,
            data:{
                var1: $('#sub_main_region').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                document.getElementById("specific_location").innerHTML=response.toString();
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could console.log your .val()

Comment: sorry i didnt understand. But please look at the second .on() function. If #main_region holds '--' then it should never call the ajax. but it does. if i select different value from #main_region then #sub_main_region fetches its value. if i select '--' in #main_region then it should not call the ajax hence the #sub_main_region should be empty. but it is not. its holds the error i provided.

Comment: ok consoling log, will let you know the result. thanks mate.

Comment: I think what Roland is asking is if you checked that you are actually getting back '--' as the value when you are selecting the 2nd one as '--'

Comment: if i select '--' in #main_region later, it holds empty string. consoled the log. why is that?

Comment: excellent Roland. Your simple idea solved it. My problem was, by writing document.getElementById("main_region').value  or  $("#main_region").val() it actually returns the value attribute not the innerHTML of the <option> tag. And I forgot it.

Comment: just few thing you have to notice : see url link in ajax, response in success method is correct, write your code in document.ready funtion